# Como implementar AutoMapper 5.0.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Configurei um projeto a um tempo atrás, da seguinte maneira,
Uma Classe chamada *AutoMapperConfig* da seguinte forma:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
            x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

uma outra classe: *DomainToViewModelMappingProfile* que faz o mapeamento de Dominio para ViewModel:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappings"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>();
    }
}
```

e uma que mapeia de ViewModel para o Domínio:

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DomainToViewModelMappings"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioViewModel>();
    }
}
```

E no **Controller** Onde chamo um método onde eu obtenho todos os usuários salvo no banco de dados

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   var UsuarioViewModel= Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Usuario>, IEnumerable<UsuarioViewModel>>(_usuarioApp.ObterTodos());
   return View(UsuarioViewModel);
 }
```

E por fim no **Global.asax** fazia a chamada do *AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();*

Com isso já funcionava perfeitamente o mapeamento para este contexto...
Porém vi que a partir da versão 4.2 do **AutoMapper** este tipo de configuração está obsoleto. Como eu faço para implementar o framework da nova forma ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Renan, neste ponto pouca coisa mudou, porém agora você precisa armazenar o seu Mapper em uma variável estática.

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.Mapper = new MapperConfiguration((mapper) =>
        {
            mapper.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
            mapper.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

Para chamar o mapper, você terá de fazer assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var UsuarioViewModel = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Usuario>, IEnumerable<UsuarioViewModel>>(_usuarioApp.ObterTodos());
    return View(UsuarioViewModel);
}
```

A chamada da configuração no `Global.asax` continua da mesma forma. Porém agora você tem o controle de como organizar e mais liberdade na configuração, podendo por exemplo criar vários `IMapper`s.

Uma sugestão, você não precisa ter um Profile para cada mapeamento, isto ajuda tanto quanto colocar todos os mapeamentos no mesmo arquivo então tente agrupar de alguma forma, por exemplo um `Profile` do `Domain`.

por fim, vejo que `Usuario` e `UsuarioViewModel` são idênticos, como não vejo nenhuma transformação ou omissão dos dados, o melhor seria que a `UsuarioController` trabalha-se direto com o `Usuario` sem precisar fazer o Mapeamento.

Comment: entendi a resposta. Agora falando da dica que deu a respeito de trabalhar direto com a classe Usuario, eu fiz por ver em algumas implementações, onde se tem uma classe ViewModel para fazer as validações com DataAnnotations e não precisar referencia-los na classe principal,  acha que fica melhor fazer isso direto na classe Usuario ?

Comment: @RenanCarlos, completamente desnecessário, o Framework tem algo bem mais apropriado e eficiente: [`How to: Add Metadata Classes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).ASPX) e [`Entity Framework Validation - IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#IValidatableObject)